# Can I use an underlay on glue down vinyl planks?

Tags: adhesive, vinyl-flooring, underlayment

I would like to reuse some luxury vinyl planks (5 year old Armstrong Luxe Plank with FasTak pressure-based adhesive, just under 4mm thick) that I pulled up from my concrete basement floor and put them in a different spot in the basement. However, they were too hard being right on the concrete. Is there an underlay I can put under and then glue them down with new adhesive?

I don’t find many people saying I can’t, and very few saying I can. I’ve seen some [flooring stores](https://timbertown.ca/choose-best-flooring-underlayment/) saying cork underlay can be used for floating or glue-down but no instructions on the latter.

> Cork underlay can be used under Hardwood, Laminate, Cork, Vinyl plank
> (LVT), carpet, tile, & marble and suitable for nail down, glue down,
> and floating installations.

I don’t care about warranty on this case, but would like to prevent annoying problems that could occur.

Answer (score 0):

is the LVP click lock?  it sounds like it might have been entirely reliant on the adhesive - if so what is your plan on re-using?  Would you put the underlay down and then glue the LVP to the underlay?

The challenge with underlay and a click lock system is that if there is enough flex the click/lock becomes disengaged or the tongue can be broken when it does flex.  The safest option is to use an underlay that has minimal compression - there are some rubber underlays that have less flex that would likely work.  You'd also be better off with a thinner underlay as there is less room for it to flex.

Comment: It is not the click together vinyl planks. They are adhesive backed and glue down next to each other. I was contemplating laying cork underlay down and then flying these to it.

Comment: i suppose even worse if there is no locking mechanism as any flex and you'll end up with trip edges - how long do you want this to last?  if you are willing to pull up and use again then quality probably isn't a top concern.  heavy items like a fridge might compress a section of the floor leaving an edge.